# Assembly language: Sorting with signed (negative) numbers and positive in ascending order.

Tags: assembly

Given 4 numbers which stored in the external memory, some of them with sign . Make a sorting, where negative numbers will be first, and then the positive . In ascending order. Stored them in that order in the external memory.

The program is written in ascending order , but it turns out that the negative numbers follow the positive.

Assembler 8051 (mcs-51)

Code:

```
        mov DPTR, #00h             ;Initial address of data pointer.

        mov A, #35d                                          
        movx @DPTR, A              ;Moves a value from accumulator into DPTR.
        inc DPTR                   ;The increment of address pointer.

        mov A, #-12d                                       
        movx @DPTR, A
        inc DPTR

        mov A, #-23d
        movx @DPTR, A
        inc DPTR

        mov A, #15d  
        movx @DPTR, A       

 ;Sorting of data will be in internal memory, after finishing, soting data will be removing to external memory again.

  sort:                            ;Start a loop of sorting by sort.
        mov R0,#28h                ;Stores address of value in proccess on DATA(28h...22h).
   lp1:   
        mov 4Ah, #00h              ;Stores a largest number.
        mov R2, DPL                ;Stores a values from DPL to remember the address of largest element.
        jmp search                 ;Jump to search.
   rt1:
        mov DPL, R2                ;Sets DPTR a lower byte to R2 (DPTR now is equal R2)
        mov A, #00h
        dec DPL                    ;The decrement of DPL.
        movx @DPTR, A 
        mov @R0, 4Ah
        dec R0
        cjne R0, #24h, lp1         ;Compare, and if not equals, jump to lp1.
        jmp data_to_xdata  
search:
        mov DPTR, #00h           
   lp2:                           
        movx A, @DPTR           
        inc DPTR
        mov R1, DPL                ;R1 as a local loop counter.
        cjne A, 4Ah, lp3                   
   rt2:
        cjne R1, #0Ah, lp2
        jmp rt1 
   lp3:
        jc  rt2                    ;Jump to rt2 if carry set equals 1.
        mov 4Ah, A
        mov R2, DPL
        jmp rt2

;Sorting fihished, so data are removing to external memory.
 xdata:                          

        mov DPTR, #00h
        mov R0,#22h
   lp4:  
        mov A, @R0                 
        movx @DPTR, A
        inc DPTR
        inc R0
        cjne R0, #4Ah, lp4      
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

The symptoms exactly match what would occur if an unsigned compare were used when it should be a signed comparison.

I am 30+ years rusty with the 8051, but from what I can tell, all of the comparisons are managing indexes of data.  If one of them is a data comparison, that would be the one to change from unsigned to signed.

Comment: It's the `lp3: jc rt2` along with the preceding `cjne A, 4Ah, lp3 `.